# How to 301 redirect removing a section of URL containing the word comment + random number

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I recently moved my website to a new domain and changed a bunch of things. In the process, I seem to have ended up generating a lot of 404 errors due to URLs like this:

mywebsite.com/theblogpost/comment-68875

This occurs on a lot of blog posts, so the blog post bit is variable as is the number at the end.
I tried experimenting with a RedEx testing tool and a htaccess tester, but it would seem that I am not smart enough to work it out

I got about as far as \b(\w*comment-\w*)\b which matched the phrase in RegEx testing but couldnt work out how to correctly apply that to a RewriteCond/RewriteRule

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but I think the important detail is how to match such incoming requests. You have to adjust the rest yourself ...

To redirect all such requests to the same target:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/comment-\d+/?$ / [R=301,END]
```

To redirect all such requests to the actual blog post:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/comment-\d+/?$ /$1 [R=301,END]
```

I used absolute path here since the question reads as if you are using the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder as base. Obviously the rules can also be implemented using relative path.

I personally clearly advise to implement such rules in the central host configuration of your http server. You can instead use a *distributed* configuration file if you are using an apache http server and if you have enabled that featture beforehand (see documentation of the `AllowOverride` directive). But that adds complexity and really slows down the http server. So only do that if you have no access to the central configuration (read: if you are using a cheap hosting provider).

Comment: That's perfect, it has worked. Thank you so much. 

Thanks for the additional advice, I shall look into it today.